# Error: '@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[2])' is incompatible with attribute checked (attr) boolean

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, data-binding

I am following the kotlin basics training camp provided by google. Currently learning shared viewmodel to build the cupcake app. I have coded exactly same as them but I am facing the below given error. For reference here is the github [repository](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-cupcake-app).

I don't know why the android studio is giving me the error. From my point of view, it is completely right. Please help me if you know how to solve this or what mistake I have done.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2020 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Layout for selecting a flavor -->
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".FlavorFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.cupcake.model.OrderViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="flavorFragment"
            type="com.example.cupcake.FlavorFragment" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/side_margin">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/flavor_options"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/vanilla"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.flavor.equals(@string/vanilla)}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setFlavor(@string/vanilla)}"
                    android:text="@string/vanilla" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/chocolate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.flavor.equals(@string/chocolate)}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setFlavor(@string/chocolate)}"
                    android:text="@string/chocolate" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/red_velvet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.flavor.equals(@string/red_velvet)}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setFlavor(@string/red_velvet)}"
                    android:text="@string/red_velvet" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/salted_caramel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.flavor.equals(@string/salted_caramel)}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setFlavor(@string/salted_caramel)}"
                    android:text="@string/salted_caramel" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/coffee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.flavor.equals(@string/coffee)}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setFlavor(@string/coffee)}"
                    android:text="@string/coffee" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                style="@style/Widget.Cupcake.Divider"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flavor_options" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtotal"
                style="@style/Widget.Cupcake.TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
                android:text="@{@string/subtotal_price(viewModel.price)}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"
                tools:text="Subtotal $5.00" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/side_margin"
                android:onClick="@{() -> flavorFragment.cancelOrder()}"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/next_button"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/next_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
                android:onClick="@{() -> flavorFragment.goToNextScreen()}"
                android:text="@string/next"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cancel_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subtotal" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

I am facing an error at the line of every **android:checked** radio button. Below is the error

```
@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[2])' is incompatible with attribute checked (attr) boolean.
```

ViewModel Code:-

```
package com.example.cupcake.model

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import java.text.NumberFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

private const val PRICE_PER_CUPCAKE = 2.00
private const val PRICE_FOR_SAME_DAY_PICKUP = 3.00

class OrderViewModel : ViewModel() {
    init {
        resetOrder()
    }
    private val _quantity = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val quantity: LiveData<Int> = _quantity

    private val _flavor = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val flavor: LiveData<String> = _flavor

    private val _date = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val date: LiveData<String> = _date

    private val _price = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    val price: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_price) {
        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(it)
    }

    val dateOptions = getPickupOptions()

    fun setQuantity(numberCupcakes: Int) {
        _quantity.value = numberCupcakes
        updatePrice()
    }

    fun setDate(pickupDate: String) {
        _date.value = pickupDate
        updatePrice()
    }

    fun setFlavor(desiredFlavor: String) {
        _flavor.value = desiredFlavor
    }


    fun hasNoFlavorSet(): Boolean {
        return _flavor.value.isNullOrEmpty()
    }

    private fun getPickupOptions(): List<String> {
        val options = mutableListOf<String>()
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM d", Locale.getDefault())
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        // Create a list of dates starting with the current date and the following 3 dates
        repeat(4) {
            options.add(formatter.format(calendar.time))
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        return options
    }

    private fun updatePrice() {
        var calculatedPrice = (quantity.value ?: 0) * PRICE_PER_CUPCAKE
        // If the user selected the first option (today) for pickup, add the surcharge
        if (dateOptions[0] == _date.value) {
            calculatedPrice += PRICE_FOR_SAME_DAY_PICKUP
        }
        _price.value = calculatedPrice
    }

    fun resetOrder() {
        _quantity.value = 0
        _flavor.value = ""
        _date.value = dateOptions[0]
        _price.value = 0.0
    }

}
```

Fragment Pick_up code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2020 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Layout for selecting a pickup date -->
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".PickupFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.cupcake.model.OrderViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="pickupFragment"
            type="com.example.cupcake.PickupFragment" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/side_margin">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/date_options"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[0])"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setDate(viewModel.dateOptions[0])}"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.dateOptions[0]}"
                    tools:text="Thursday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked= "@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[1])}"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setDate(viewModel.dateOptions[1])}"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.dateOptions[1]}"
                    tools:text="Friday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[2])"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setDate(viewModel.dateOptions[2])}"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.dateOptions[2]}"
                    tools:text="Saturday" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[3])"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setDate(viewModel.dateOptions[3])}"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.dateOptions[3]}"
                    tools:text="Sunday" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                style="@style/Widget.Cupcake.Divider"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/side_margin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_options" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtotal"
                style="@style/Widget.Cupcake.TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"
                android:text="@{@string/subtotal_price(viewModel.price)"
                tools:text="Subtotal $5.00" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margin"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:onClick="@{() -> pickupFragment.goToNextScreen()}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subtotal" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you share your viewModel and complete logcat screenshot ?

Comment: done. I can't share the whole logcat because it contains a lot of things. You can see the error that I have shared.

Comment: Can you share you fragment_pickup ?, there is something wrong in that fragment data binding

Comment: done. I have shared

Comment: You can go to FragmentPickupBindingImpl using Debugger and here check this line  of code             androidx.databinding.adapters.CompoundButtonBindingAdapter.setChecked(this.option2, viewModelDateEqualsViewModelDateOptions2);
Maybe something is wrong here like some value is getting null or  incompatible data type are getting compared.